# Gzipper with angular 15 for reducing size of js files

Tags: compression, gzip, angular15

I'm using the gzipped utility to reduce the size of the main.js file with angular 15. However, I am not able to reduce the size of main.js as well as other js files for production.

Following is the link which I already followed, but no success.

[How to compress Angular 11 application prod files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594799/how-to-compress-angular-11-application-prod-files)

I have also used "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress ./dist" but it results in: 'gzipper' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Attached is the screenshot showing the actual size for different js files.

[main.js file size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6CrD.png)